# Unable to find "Proxies\__CG__\App\MyBundle\Entity\User" entity identifier associated with the UnitOfWork

Tags: symfony, orm, symfony5, php-7.4

I updated a Symfony project from version 3.4 to 5.3, and after that, I am getting the following error on some pages:

```
Unable to find "Proxies\__CG__\App\MyBundle\Entity\User" entity identifier associated with the UnitOfWork at /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityNotFoundException.php line 43
```

Maybe Symfony has a way to get more detailed information about the error? Or maybe there is some config to ignore this error?

Comment: Were you able to determine the issue here? I'm getting the same issue after upgrading and think it might be tied to my postFlush event handlers.